# Program to evaluate postfix expressions but there is a wierd problem with this program-it does not gives output and instead gives a long error

Tags: c++, stack

I was writing a code for postfix expression evaluation and encountered a weird error. it shows a big error which is really difficult for me to understand what is wrong in the code.
it would be really helpful if you please have a look and tell me what's wrong with it or what mistake I have made.
I have listed the code below to have a look.
**thank you in advance**

here is the code :

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int evaluate(string expression);

bool Isdigit(char c);

bool IsOprator(char c);

int performcalc(char opration,int op2,int op1);

int main(){
    string expression;
    cout<<"Start of the program ! "<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter a postfix expression to evaluate: ";
    cin>>expression;
    int result = evaluate(expression);
    cout<<"Result ="<<result<<endl;
    cout<<"End of the program !!";
    return 0;
}

int evaluate(string expression){
    stack <char> S;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < expression.length(); i++)
    {
        if (expression[i] == ' ' || expression[i] == ',')
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (Isdigit(expression[i]))
        {
            int a = stoi(expression[i]);
            S.push(a);
        }
        
        else if (IsOprator(expression[i]))
        {
            int op2 = S.top(); S.pop();
            int op1 = S.top(); S.pop();
            int result = performcalc(expression[i],op2,op1);
            S.push(result);
        }
    }
    return S.top();
}

bool Isdigit(char c){
    if (c >= '0' && c<='9')
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    
}

bool IsOprator(char c){
    if (c == '+' || c == '*' || c == '/' || c == '-' )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    
}

int performcalc(char opration,int op2,int op1){
    if (opration == '+')
    {
        return op1+op2;
    }
    else if (opration == '-')
    {
        return op1-op2;
    }
    else if (opration == '*')
    {
        return op1*op2;
    }
    else if (opration == '/')
    {
        return op1/op2;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

***Error :***

```
Postfix_evaluation_using_stack.cpp: In function 'int evaluate(std::string)':
Postfix_evaluation_using_stack.cpp:37:39: error: no matching function for call to 'stoi(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, ch
ar>::value_type&)'
   37 |             int a = stoi(expression[i]);
      |                                       ^
In file included from c:\ming\mingw\include\c++\9.2.0\string:55,
                 from c:\ming\mingw\include\c++\9.2.0\bits\locale_classes.h:40,
                 from c:\ming\mingw\include\c++\9.2.0\bits\ios_base.h:41,
                 from c:\ming\mingw\include\c++\9.2.0\ios:42,
                 from c:\ming\mingw\include\c++\9.2.0\ostream:38,
                 from c:\ming\mingw\include\c++\9.2.0\iostream:39,
                 from Postfix_evaluation_using_stack.cpp:1:
c:\ming\mingw\include\c++\9.2.0\bits\basic_string.h:6503:3: note: candidate: 'int std::__cxx11::stoi(const string&, std::size_t*, int)'
 6503 |   stoi(const string& __str, size_t* __idx = 0, int __base = 10)
      |   ^~~~
c:\ming\mingw\include\c++\9.2.0\bits\basic_string.h:6503:22: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<st
d::allocator<char>, char>::value_type' {aka 'char'} to 'const string&' {aka 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&'}
 6503 |   stoi(const string& __str, size_t* __idx = 0, int __base = 10)
      |        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
c:\ming\mingw\include\c++\9.2.0\bits\basic_string.h:6609:3: note: candidate: 'int std::__cxx11::stoi(const wstring&, std::size_t*, int)'
 6609 |   stoi(const wstring& __str, size_t* __idx = 0, int __base = 10)
      |   ^~~~
c:\ming\mingw\include\c++\9.2.0\bits\basic_string.h:6609:23: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<st
d::allocator<char>, char>::value_type' {aka 'char'} to 'const wstring&' {aka 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t>&'}
 6609 |   stoi(const wstring& __str, size_t* __idx = 0, int __base = 10)
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Please include the error message in the question.

Comment: Compilation errors should be addressed one at a time from the top down.  Often, fixing one will fix several more further downstream.

Comment: `void main` -- That should be `int main()`, not `void main()`.

Comment: `if (expression == ' ' || expression == ',')` you are trying to compare the whole string to a character. Did you want to use `expression[i]` instead of `expression`?

Comment: I guess you know that your code can only work if the numbers in the expression are positive and less than 9.

Comment: `cin>>expression;` is problematic. Remember the `cin` reads up to the first whitespace character typed.

Comment: @Sean i have updated the question and included the error

Comment: @Yksisarvinen  i have updated the question and included the error

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thank you paul but it does not fix it !

Comment: @drescherjm thank you sir , bit i have updated it and tried but it is still giving error

Comment: @drescherjm right sir but if any space is inserted the first if loop will eliminate it in the beginning only . i think it does not effect our code !!

Comment: To clarify `cin>>expression;` will stop reading after any space. So if the person typed `1 + 1` and pressed enter the `expression` variable will be `1` The rest `+ 1` will be left in the input stream for future reads. You may want to read a line at a time.

Comment: @RishabhYadav -- The comment section is for comments, not for answers.  The fix for your problem will be posted in the Answer section.  The comment was made so that you fix the code to make it valid C++.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ohh soo sorry sir , I am new to this and will not be doing this mistake again !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to compare a `std::string` with a `char`:

```
if (expression == ' ' || expression == ',')
```

Change it to:

```
if (expression == " " || expression == ",")
```

The `string` class doesn't support comparisons with single characters, hence the error.

Also, this is wrong:

```
int a = stoi(expression[i]);
```

`stoi` needs a `string`, you are passing a `char`. Change it to:

```
int a = stoi(expression);
```

And your stack is wrong:

```
stack <char> S;
```

It should be a stack of integers, not char:

```
stack <int> S;
```

Comment: sorry sir , but it is still giving error

Comment: @RishabhYadav = I've updated the answer

Comment: Thank you sir ..its working now i just replaced the conversion of char to int to manually conversion but now the code is not giving any output after supplying a postfix expression .. can you have a look if i post it in the question itself ??